# Different pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I have recently encountered a peculiar  thing. While I was watching a Youtuber from England I heard him pronounce words like "everybody", "God" etc the American way with an /ɑ/ instead of an /ɒ/. This seems strange to me because in any other words which had the same sound he pronounced it the English way with an /ɒ/. I did some research about it and I found that there are other people who use the American phoneme only in certain words like those above and stick to /ɒ/ for the others. Is this a feature of modern speech in England? Is it considered odd to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: England, indeed Britain, has many different accents and dialects. Your question seems to assume there is only one.

Comment: I know there are a lot of accents and dialects in Britain, but I have never encountered one with this feature of inconsistently pronouncing /ɒ/.This is why I was wondering if it is just a different accent or an influence of American English.

Comment: ɒ, the open back rounded vowel is the 'o' used in words like of, from, God, etc in Received Pronunciation and many English regional accents. The ɑ sound, the open back unrounded vowel, is usually the 'a' in after, past, ask. Some regional accents/dialects including very upper class 'cut glass' speech might use it in place of the rounded vowel. I would be able to identify which one if you gave a link to an example of the Youtuber's speech. Otherwise we're just guessing. Are you sure the person is British?

Comment: https://youtu.be/YBujvmcvpg0. At the beginning where he says "everybody".

Comment: To me that sounds like "ev'rybudy". Later on he uses the Southern English/RP ɒ vowel in 'of', 'on', etc, so I would regard that 'everybody' as an aberration. I would also say that his chief claim to being a pronunciation 'expert' is that he thinks he is one. This is common on Youtube. His accent is fairly RP but with a noticeable dash of Estuary.

Comment: If he is affecting an american pronunciation, then it's ironic that the video should be titled "Sound more British".

Comment: Thank you, guys! Now I understand that he is not really so much of an expert and that his pronunciation of that phoneme is not representative of any English accent, but is simply a mix.

Comment: When  does he say "God"? And BTW, he is incorrect in referring to "linking r" and "intrusive r" as being the same thing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R

Comment: [Here](http://all-about-linguistics.group.shef.ac.uk/branches-of-linguistics/varieties-of-english/language-attitudes-and-opinions/) is a link which shows you the variation between the different accents and dialects Britain has: they all pronounce "Very few cars made it up the long hill" differently.

Comment: @user69503 That's just how it is, no one has a monotonous British RP accent in Britain--even if they did, recent estimates says that [only 2% of the population speak it](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/find-out-more/received-pronunciation/). There are other factors which affect how people pronounce words other than dialects and also if you move around a lot and meet people with different accents, you may start to eventually imitate their accent and then it becomes a part of your dialect as well.

Comment: @aesking: "if you move around a lot and meet people with different accents, you may start to eventually imitate their accent and then it becomes a part of your dialect as well. ". I was born in south London to a middle class parent from Derby and a working class one from Camberwell, went to public school on a scholarship, and have lived in Bristol for 40 years, the last 25 of these with a lady from Lancashire. Elements advance and recede depending on context. Unfettered by context, I am pretty much RP.